# Why are they called schematic "capture" programs?

Tags: software, schematics

What are you capturing the schematic from?  Makes me think of a butterfly net or something.

Comment: Maybe it makes engineers feel like conquerors: today we capture the schematic; tomorrow the world! Muwah ha ha ha ha!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name comes from the days (not necessarily long past) when a circuit would be designed on paper and then entered into computer later.

The electronics design world is strangely conservative, some of these guys still swear by MS-DOS.

Comment: and not 6.22, either, 5.0 was the last best DOS! =P

Comment: We've still got Windows 98 on some of the computers at work.  :)  I don't think the software even runs on anything modern.

Comment: Similar uses are 'knowledge capture', 'data capture', 'video capture' - the term is used for things which exists outside of the computer and are converted into a form the computer can then process.

Answer (score 4):

They "capture" the netlist from the schematic.

Or "capture" the schematic from paper? (It's still faster to draw the schematic on paper first.)

Comment: If you could draw a schematic on paper, scan it, and have it automatically converted to a netlist, then it would be appropriate to call it "schematic capture", in my opinion

Comment: I would buy such a program...

Comment: I like the netlist reason.  After all, it is that net list that you have to feed into so many other tools.

Comment: I go with the netlist reason.  A lot of people write textual documents on paper and then key them into a computer, but I've never heard a word processing app called a "document capture" program.  The part of a "schematic capture" program that produces the netlist will typically represent a tiny portion of the program's complexity, but will be absolutely vital to the program's usefulness.

Answer (score 3):

From the mind of the designer.

Comment: +! to capture the ideas of the mind